# Create pivot table from 2D array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, pivot-table

I'm trying to build a pivot table based on the values stored in a 2D variant array. something like this:

```
Function createPivot(dataRng As Variant) As PivotTable
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim rngDates As Range
    Dim pv As PivotTable
    Dim SrcData As String, StartPvt As String
    Dim pvtTableName As String
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    
    Sheets(pvSheet).Cells.Clear
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(pvSheet)
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(WBPATH)
    
    pvtTableName = "mytablename"
    
    SrcData = dataRng ' HERE!
    
    StartPvt = sh.Name & "!" & sh.Range("A1").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) 'Cells(4, lastCol).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
    
    'Next line crashes:
    ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        SrcData, Version:=6). _
        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=StartPvt, TableName:=pvtTableName, _
        DefaultVersion:=`

[etc...]

    createPivot = pv
end function
```

Is there a way of creating a pivot table from a variant variable?

Comment: put the array in a hidden sheet and use that?

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to avoid that so I wouldn't end up with a huge file size but I don't see any workaround it. Seems that pivot tables must be linked with worksheet ranges

Comment: @David Hey, David. It shouldn't impact file size terribly. You could theoretically load the array into a "xlveryhidden" worksheet and then delete that data from the same sheet at the end of the macro. I am actually looking for a similar solution as you right now, however